# How to get the code from FDA Tool box?

Tags: filter, matlab, multiplication

In Filter Design HDL Coder, while designing for nonmultirate filter, there is a option 'CSD' (canonical signed digit) from 'Coeff multipliers' menu in the Filter settings (for optimizing coefficient multipliers).

I need to speed up a system. For that reason, i need the code for CSD multiplier.

Can anyone please give me any idea how i can get the code for CSD multiplier from FDA toolbox or from any other source?